# Will pets stores test my aquarium water?

Tags: aquarium, fish, water-parameters

If I have a fish and I don't have the skills and/or supplies to test the water in my fish tank, can I take a sample from the fish tank to the fish/pet store to get tested?

If yes, what if any special considerations are there?

Comment: They will because then can sell you all sorts of additives to "fix" it.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a good fish store, they will most likely provide basic water testing for free or for a nominal charge. Look for privately owned ones with good reviews and call them to see what they offer. If you have any local aquarium clubs, I'm sure you can get this answer for your area or even get a member to help you out. I would stay far away from big box pet stores, petco and petsmart, if you want quality service, knowledge, or livestock.